# Lookup Employee ID from Name and Employees ID and display name in the next cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to lookup the EMP ID in the row and try to match with the Lookup table and if found return the name of the employee in the next cell

[image]

Comment: INDEX(MATCH()) will do this.

Comment: `XLOOKUP` will also do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. For instance in the image below:

[image]

the formula `=INDEX($F$4:$F$5,MATCH(B5,$G$4:$G$5,0))` returns `Kishore`.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Instead of B5, I needed to look up emp id from A5